# AWS S3 SDK: Abort a putObject upload in progress

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm currently uploading files to an S3 bucket using putObject

```
params = {
    Key: videoKey,
    ContentType: file.type,
    Body: file,
    ACL: "public-read"
};

req = s3.putObject(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
    // calculate percentage complete
    var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded / evt.total * 100);

    $cancelBtn.on("click", function(evt) {
      req.abort.bind(req); // doesn't work; returns an error
    });
}).send(function(err, data) {
    // code to handle what happens after upload completes
});
```

I've read in multiple locations to use `req.abort()` or `req.abort.bind(req)`, but this seems to be returning the following error:

```
'req.abort is not a function. (In 're.abort()', 'req.abort' is undefined)'
```

It's true `'req'` doesn't seem to have an `abort()` function in its Object, so I'm wondering if this is just tied to an older version of the AWS SDK. If so, what's the proper way to deal with this? I've read some documentation on Amazon's website for a method called **abortMultipartUpload** but this method requires an **UploadId** and I can't figure how to retrieve this from my `putObject` function. How do I retrieve a response with an `UploadID` before the `'send'` callback?

Thanks for any help!

-Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The S3 PUTObject API is not a multi-part request. The `abortMultipartUpload` or `completeMultipartUpload` is required or can be used when you initiate the multi-part request using `createMultipartUpload`. The response of `createMultipartUpload` API returns the `uploadId` value.

> createMultipartUpload(params = {}, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request Initiates a
>   multipart upload and returns an upload ID.Note: After you initiate
>   multipart upload and upload one or more parts, you must either
>   complete or abort multipart upload in order to stop getting charged
>   for storage of the uploaded parts.

**Multi-part upload steps:-**

1) Multi-part upload initiation - API `createMultipartUpload`

2) Parts upload - API are `upload` or `uploadPart`

3) Multi-part upload completion (or Abort) - API `abortMultipartUpload` or `completeMultipartUpload`